# Over sequential spaces and $B(H)$

Tags: general-topology, convergence-divergence, operator-algebras

We say that a topological space $X$ is sequential if the following holds : If $U$ is sequentially open then $U$ is open. By sequentially open we mean that $x \in U$ and $x_n \to x$ implies that $x_n$ lies eventually in $U$.

My questions:

1. Is there a characterization of sequential spaces ?
2. Can one replace the phrase "nets" by "sequences" everywhere ? For example: A function is continuous iff $f(x_n) \to f(x)$ whenever $x_n \to x$ or a subset $K \subset X$ is compact iff each sequence in $K$ has a convergent subsequence.
3. How does one prove that $B(H)$ is not sequential in the weak / strong topology, where $H$ is a separable Hilbert space and $B(H)$ the set of bounded operators acting on $H$.

Comment: You’ll find three characterizations of sequential spaces [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_space#Equivalent_conditions). The first two are proved in the $1965$ paper by Stan Franklin noted in the References section of that article. The answer to your second question is *yes*: sequential spaces are precisely those in which the topology is completely determined by the sequences.

Comment: Thank you. Do you have any suggestions on 3. ?

Comment: I’m afraid not, at least not off the top of my head; it’s been a *long* time since I had any reason to think about objects like $B(H)$.